# How to change Kotlin's 'this property has a backing field' code editor highlight in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

My goodness, this default color highlighting for IntelliJ is blinding. How can I change this?

[image]

Comment: It _is_ blinding isn't it ... Not quite sure what they were thinking when they selected those colours. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You modify the Kotlin colour highlighting the same way you do for any other syntax highlighting.  You'll find it under `Preferences` > `Colors & Fonts` > `Kotlin`.

The item you want is `Property with backing field`.  Note however that [KT-6765](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6765#) is a bug I found where the foreground colour is not respected unless you also set a background colour.  Therefore, to change it, make sure you set both a foreground and a background colour as shown below:

[image]

Personally I opted for a dark background that roughly approximated the Darcula default background.

Comment: And could you explain, what is a backing field and why is it being highlighted?

Comment: I've seen this, but did't get it

Comment: @Defuera yeah I agree, so far this is the most confusing thing about `Kotlin` for me

Comment: @Defuera I _see_ it but don't get it.

Comment: If I understand it correctly this is just needed to make custom getter/setter possible without causing an infinite recursion. Getter causes StackOverflow, setter works.
 `class Monkey(val name: String, val type: String = "Gibbon") {
    var empty: Boolean = false
        get() {
            if (empty == true)
                return false
            else
                return true
        }
        set(value) {
            if (value == true)
                field = false
            else
                field = true
        }`