# What is the correct way to deal with fields in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

How should I handle the migration from a Java class with fields to Kotlin properly?

A couple of reading into Kotlin's docs reveal that their classes can't have fields defined within them. Being the rebel that I am, actually trying to convert my existing Java code to its Kotlin counterpart (using Android Studio's Java to Kotlin converter feature) also marks "fields" with an [unpleasantly blinding highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28945392/how-to-change-kotlins-this-property-has-a-backing-field-code-editor-highlight).

This is my Java class:

```
  public final class PaperDay implements Day {
    private Date date;
    private Weather weather;

    PaperDay() {
      // Obligatory empty ctor for Paper.
    }

    PaperDay(Date date) {
      this.date = truncateTimeFromDate(date);
      this.weather = Weather.SUNNY; // Default to SUNNY, 'cos sunny is good!
    }

    PaperDay(Date date, Weather weather) {
      this.date = truncateTimeFromDate(date);
      this.weather = weather;
    }

    private Date truncateTimeFromDate(Date date) {
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

      calendar.setTime(date);

      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      ...
```

..and this is what it looks like converted into a .kt:

[image]

How can I do this the Kotlin way?

Comment: Because of the 'blinding highlight'.

Comment: shouldn't it be enough to just remove the `private var ...` lines? you already defined the fields in the constructor. you should also get rid of the second constructor by using an optional parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want something like this:

```
class PaperDay (private var date: Date, 
                private var weather: Weather = Weather.SUNNY) : Day {
    init {
        this.date = truncate(date)
    }

    private fun truncateTimeFromDate(date1: Date): Date {
        return date1
    }
}
```

You should try to use optional parameters (`var weather: Weather = Weather.SUNNY`) wherever you can, since it increases readability a lot.

To avoid the (somewhat ugly) `init` block you can also pass only one of the two properties as a constructor parameter (thanks to Jayson Minard), and calculate the other property in it's declaration by using a "normal" paramter:

```
class PaperDay (dateWithTime: Date, 
                private val weather: Weather = Weather.SUNNY): Day {

    private val date: Date = truncateTimeFromDate(dateWithTime)

    ...
}
```

Note that this is also using `val` instead of `var` since immutability is usually the better option.

If you need to have the empty constructor as well, you can add this (although I don't think it's a good practice and it's an indicator for "bad" 
design:

```
 constructor() : this(Date())
```

Alternatively, adding a default value for *all* parameters in the constructor will implicitly create an empty constructor as well.

if you really want the nullability define your properties using `?`. E.g.:

```
class PaperDay (private var date: Date?, private var weather: Weather? = Weather.SUNNY)
```

you can then also change the other constructor to `constructor() : this(null)`

---

Additionally, it's IMHO also a good idea to add the `truncate...` method as an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) for the Date class instead of heaving it in this class:

```
fun Date.truncateTimeFromDate() {
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

  calendar.setTime(this)

  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
  calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think he still needs a default constructor @Lovis for his given framework, so not a choice he can make.

Comment: you have the accepted answer, feel free to update it even if it takes ideas from the other answer.  Make your accepted the best possible.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Lovis but avoiding the use of `var` which should be a "last resort":

```
class PaperDay (dateWithTime: Date = Date(), private val weather: Weather = Weather.SUNNY): Day {
    private val date: Date = truncateTimeFromDate(dateWithTime)

    private fun truncateTimeFromDate(dateWithTime : Date) : Date {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this version, the constructor has *one parameter* that is not a class property, and the other is a property.  Later in the class body, the property is declared and set to the truncated date.

If you have a default value for each constructor parameter, Kotlin will automatically create a default constructor that uses those defaults.  No need to add it separately.

If your framework must instantiate with default constructor and then set the values after the fact, you'll want to do something more like the following and go back to using `var`:

```
class PaperDay (dateWithTime: Date = Date(), private var weather: Weather = Weather.SUNNY): Day {
    private var date: Date = truncateTimeFromDate(dateWithTime)
       set(value) { field = truncateTimeFromDate(value) }

    private fun truncateTimeFromDate(dateWithTime : Date) : Date {
        return dateWithTime
    }
}
```

Now we have ensured we never have a invalid date being stored in the property by having a custom setter.

If you want interoperability for all variations of the constructor available from Java, you can use the [`@JvmOverloads` annotation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation) on the constructor to generate other permutations of using default parameter values.

And as @Lovis points out, move the `truncateTimeFromDate` to an extension function on the `Date` class.  It can be local to the file, to the module, to the class, and in all those cases it will read better.

Comment: `private val date: Date = truncateTimeFromDate(dateWithTime)` didn't think about that. Cool! Also _"default parameters for each constructor parameter also gives you a default () constructor"_ is pretty smart

Comment: Kotlin has many nice things :-) , I updated this to have a custom setter to enforce the date truncation if set later.